# Selenium WebDriver does not find element by XPATH

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to write a Selenium Testcase and started with the Selenium IDE in Firefox.
The test is working quite fine there. Now I want to automate that test with Selenium Webdriver and exported the according JAVA class.
Everything is setup and working fine so far (the Internet Explorer window is opening, the according page is displayed).

BUT: Selenium Webdriver does not find the element.
I want to get the following element:

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-instance/status" unselectable="on">Open</div>
```

and I have the following code:

```
    WebElement openWorkItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Open')]"));
System.out.println(openWorkItem.getText());
```

In the testcase with Selenium IDE the statement is pretty much the same, and it is working:

```
<td>//div[contains(text(),'Open')]</td>
```

The only difference is, that the Selenium IDE is only available in Firefox, but in the end I want to have the test executed in IE with Selenium WebDriver.

Any help is very much appreciated.

**==Update==**
I executed `driver.getPageSource()` and now see that the HTML part I am looking for is not available because it seems to be located in an iFrame. Any ideas?

Comment: tried `//div[text()='Open']`?

Comment: thx for the suggestion. I tried it, but it does not work either.

Comment: does the page use frames? if so, frames are treated differently by browsers, so the first frame could be frame[0] for IE 6,7,8,9 but W3C defines the first as frame[1]. To solve this problem in IE, set the SelectionLanguage to XPath.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923718/need-help-in-getting-xpath-expression-for-span-inside-an-iframe-popup

Comment: Yes it uses frames - I updated my initial question. How do I set the SelectionLanguage?

Comment: "Any ideas?" - Yes, switch to that `iframe` before you try to find the element.

Comment: Okay. Got the idea. I'm trying to switch to the iframe. Problem is: part of the iframe id is generated when loading the page. So when I try to do `driver.switchTo().frame("DetailTab-ext-gen23-810870");` it fails, because the last sequence (810870) is now different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use findElement to get the frame webelement and have it used with the switchto() method.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("iframe[contains(@name=pngNewC‌​ase1143241142570_IFrame)]")));
```

If you have some other attribute like src, you can try the below.

```
WebElement frame=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='showNewClaimForm.action']");
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```