# C# Find everything between <TR></TR> Tags and sort it into strings

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, sorting

I'm making a program that will sort a huge table on a website into a more manageable and customizable display.

Class represents what the content is tt=text nn=number. Here's an example of what one of the tags looks like. All of them are exactly the same except for the values between the tags.

```
<TR class=r2>
    <TD class=tt headers=0>SOME_Text_here_ending_in_Vi.SG2</TD>
    <TD class=nn headers=1>0</TD>
    <TD class=nn headers=2>0</TD>
    <TD class=nn headers=3>0</TD>
    <TD class=nn headers=4>0</TD>
    <TD class=nn style="COLOR: ; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00cc00" 
    headers=5>00:00:00</TD>
    <TD class=nn style="COLOR: ; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #00cc00" 
    headers=6>00:00:00</TD>
    <TD class=nn headers=7>7</TD>
    <TD class=nn headers=8>13</TD>
</TR>
```

There are ~300 of those on the page. I managed to get the first `<TD>` of every `<TR>` by using RegEx `(?-imsx:" + system + "_*(.?)*_Vi)` - system being what I sort them by. However I still need the rest of the information from the `<TR>` tag as it is related to the search.

My goal is to create a smaller table in a ListBox that has the sorted results displayed based on what I submit in the "system" variable.

What is the best way to scan the whole source HTML of a page and pick it apart tag by tag sorting them as I wish. From what I found on here so far it seems that RegEx cannot be used to parse HTML like I want, so what other ways can I achieve that?

Comment: It looks like you are working with `WebBrowser` component. I think it will be easier if you access the `HtmlDocument` and get the elements by ID or tag name, and then access the TD contents you need.

Comment: Use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse HTML

Comment: Please do NOT use regex for parsing Html as it gets endlessly complicated when nesting elements. Instead use some ready-to use html-parser, e.g. htmlagilitypack.

Comment: Yes I have a `WebBrowser` in my program which is where I get the raw HTML from instead of actually downloading from the net. I will look into the `HtmlAgilityPack` hopefully it'll let me separate and sort each tag properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a perfect tool for this. Having your HTML in a string, you load it like this:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
```

and then you have powerful things like XPath that will help you in your task.

So, let's say you want to get all TRs inside your document and then you want to do something with their TD childs:

```
        HtmlNode docNode = doc.DocumentNode;
        HtmlNodeCollection trNodes = docNode.SelectNodes("//tr"); 

        foreach (HtmlNode trNode in trNodes)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection tdNodes = trNode.SelectNodes("td"); 
            // Here you have TD elements in a collection and you can process it
        }
```

Comment: I could be doing something wrong but I can't seem to make it find the TR or TD nodes. It finds the TBODY and the TH, but can't seem to go past that

Comment: So digging further it seems like it doesn't like the xPath. Trying to fiddle around with it so far not getting any luck. All the TD tags are the same in terms of their class and only the values they contain are different so how can I get the xPath to categorize them and not jumble them together?

Comment: Could you please share your code as it will be much easier to identify the problem with it.

Comment: Thx I got it solved. Was just using the wrong xPath. Found it by using dev console in chrome and copying the path to the TD tag. Used `docNode.SelectNodes(//*[@id='tbody']/tr[1]/td[1]);` Can I use something similar to extract the BG Color?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack allows you to get attributes of elements - tdNode.Attributes["style"] will give you the whole contents of the style attribute. Use regex to extract the BG color value from that.

Comment: Yeah I figured to use the outerHtml and just get BG Color hex using RegEx. Now the solution for the xPath I posted above worked for a cached page that I have. However the live page contains the dataset in an iFrame which is in another iFrame. I managed to get the xPath to that `/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]` but get an error Expression must evaluate to a node-set. What's the difference between this xpath and the first one? Won't they lead to the same place?

Comment: Would really need to see the actual code. Note that you do not need to have a full path to the element in XPath. For example, if you your XPath is "//table" it will give you all the table elements in the document. So, if you only have tables that are under the body/div element, you can use it safely and write "//table/tbody/tr..." instead of "/html/body/div/table..."

Comment: Ok that makes sense. My problem is that the table is 4 iFrames deep into the website. The HTML source of the actual URL I go to does not contain the table. It loads a report viewer which calls a bunch of IDs from a server so I can't just link to the actual GridView of the table cuz that URL contains IDs which change and so on. I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814916/how-do-i-select-elements-inside-an-iframe-with-xpath) although it's python that there's a way to load up the iFrames and access them somehow. Now to figure out how. Any suggestion for C#?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) is not a browser or an HTTP client, it is a parser. This means that you do not use it to download the page, you use it to parse the page. In C#, you can use HttpWebRequest, for example, to download the page. So, first you download the page, then load your code to HAP. This is single page, so any iframes are just simple elements, the pages they link to are not a part of that code. So you find your iframe, extract the "src" attribute and you load that target page with HTTP client again. You the load its code to HAP, find your iframe ... repeat until your have the final page

Comment: I don't think that you really have a HTML code (that you load to HAP) that contains iframe and that iframe is filled with HTML code of the page it references. I would be surprised if you had that. Could you please confirm that that is not the case (if you can confirm that then my previous comment is the solution).

Comment: That's the problem. If the HTML code contained the `src=` in the `iframe` tag then I'd have no problem. However when the site loads the source is `src=""` and then a script runs to get the source. I can still get that source, but it's not that simple as there is another `iframe` in there that does the same thing. `src=""` is empty and a 3k line script gets the elements to put in the src url such as 3 different IDs 2 of which I can see in the script. Is there a way to load the page then actually load the iframe element - wait for it to load - then open the iframe inside it? Can Selenium do it?

Comment: And on top of that the `src=` of the first iFrame doesn't seem to resolve in an actual usable page. When pulling the site in DOM it shows `#text` instead of the actual `<html>` andso the [xPath Finder](https://hapxpathfinder.codeplex.com/) can't even read into the `iframe` so any time I try to load it I get `null` for `innerHTML` So I'm looking for something that can load the site fully like a browser run all the scripts it has and open all frames and then be able to go through and pull the correct frame that's in another frame.

Comment: OK! I GOT IT! I managed to get the `src=` of a page where the data is contained! I used 
`foreach (HtmlWindow frame in webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames)
            {
                html += ((mshtml.HTMLIFrame)(frame.Frames[1].Frames[0].WindowFrameElement.DomElement)).src;
            }` 
and it gets me the source to which I can just get all the data I need!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Linq to Xml. Not tested it, but it shuld be something like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(htmlCode);
var tds = xdoc.Root.Descendants().Where(el => el.Name == "TD");
// tds is a collection of all TD elements of the htmlCode
```