# Unable to identify element in Blue Prism using XPath

Tags: xpath, blueprism

I have spied an input text box using the Application Modeller of Blue Prism and was able to successfully highlight the text box using the below XPath:

/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(4)/main(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/IFRAME(1)/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(2)/FORM(1)/DIV(3)/TABLE(2)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/SPAN(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/INPUT(1)

I wanted to use a more robust XPath and to achieve that I was trying to use the below XPath:

//*[@id="CT"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td/input[1]

The above XPath was identifying the element correctly in Chrome but was getting the below error message when trying the same in Blue Prism:

Error - Highlighting results - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Let me know if I am doing anything incorrectly.

Comment: The problem is that there's is an iframe in the middle of the xpath. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814916/how-do-i-select-elements-inside-an-iframe-with-xpath).

Comment: I tried for different element as well, but it is even not working for web pages without the iframe.

Does Blueprism allows Relative XPath at all?

Comment: I don't believe the `Path` attribute in Blue Prism is XPath compatible. Have you seen any documentation to the contrary?

Comment: This XPath is working for me: /HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(4)/main(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/IFRAME(1)/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(2)/FORM(1)/DIV(3)/TABLE(2)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/SPAN(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/INPUT(1) - I wanted to use a relative XPath

Comment: Blue Prism only works whit IE.

Comment: Yes, I am trying this in IE only, I was checking whether my relative Xpath path was correct or not by testing it in chrome

Comment: I believe it is not xpath compatible and the other bad thing is as soon as you try using wildcards/regexes like "*/INPUT"+matchindex, it slows down to a crawl and becomes unusable on big pages.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for replying to a pretty old one! The workaround we've devised for this scenario (where making the path dynamic requires too long of a loop / search) is to use Jquery snippets. If the page is using jquery it is trivial to execute these queries very quickly using the blue prism capability of executing javascript functions.

And we put in an enhancement request, because it'd be supremely useful functionality.

Update: As a user points out below, the vanilla js querySelector method is probably safer and more future proof than using jquery if it is possible to be used.

Comment: Same here! I would add that in many use cases the elements can be identified with a vanilla document.querySelector call without jquery.

Comment: Yes, we actually discovered that recently working with a site that stopped using jquery in an update!  

I suspect Jquery may still be needed for taking some exotic actions on inputs but am going to try to avoid it in the future based off that experience.

Answer (score 0):

Blue Prism does not fully support the XPath spec; alas the construct you're attempting to use here won't work.

Alternatively, you can set the `Path` attribute of an application modeler entry to be Dynamic, which allows you to insert dynamic parameters from the process/object level to pinpoint elements you'd like to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Blue Prism doesn't actually use "real" XPaths, but only an extremely limited subset: Absolute paths without wildcards. (Note: It *is* technically possible to match the XPath to a string with wildcards, but this seemingly causes BP to check every single element in the document, and is so slow it is almost never the right solution.)

For cases where an element can't be robustly identified via the BP application modeler (maybe because it requires complex or dynamic selectors), my workaround is to inject a JS snippet. JS can select elements much more reliably, and it can then generate the BluePrism path for that element.

Returning data from JS to BluePrism is not trivial, but one of the nicer solutions is to have JS create a `<script id="_output">` element, put JSON inside it, then have BluePrism read the contents of this element.