# Python Finding element by XPath

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

For reference visit https://rabirius.me/2020/02/14/bird-watching/ (not my website)

You may see a Like button there near a reblog button

I want python to click that but I get an error stating

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div[2]/a"}
```

The code i wrote was

```
for posts in open_links:
       bot.get(posts)
       sleep(4)
       bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/a').click()
       sleep(2)
```

The HTML of the like button is

```
<div class="wpl-button like">
            <a href="#" title="177 bloggers like this." class="like sd-button" rel="nofollow">
                <span>Like</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Any Help would be Appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you have the right xPath? I think it might be /html/body/div/div/div[1]/a

Comment: check with `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.like.sd-button").click()`

Comment: This should help: [How do I select elements inside an iframe with Xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816113/8667436)

Answer (score 1):

An iframe is present on the page, so you need to first switch to that iframe and then operate on the element and its recommended to use explicit wait to wait for the element to be present on the page.
You can do it like:

```
for posts in open_links:
   bot.get(posts)
   driver.switch_to.frame(bot.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
   like_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'wpl-likebox')]//span[text()='Like']")))
   like_element.click()
```

You need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: when I use your code, I get this message that WebDriverWait is not defined, Ec is not defined By is not defined, Kindly Help

Comment: @ArjunBasandrai you need to add the imports. I have added those in my ans, please pick the updated ans

Comment: which imports do I need to add
Please explain, I am quite New to Python

Comment: @ArjunBasandrai i have updated my answer and added that in my answer, please check my updated ans

Comment: I tried to put it in a try or except statement inside the for loop to see what it shows

There I am getting this error
```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe class="post-likes-widget jetpack-likes-widget" name="like-post-frame-30202391-21519-5e8e8570d7c98" height="55px" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="//widgets.wp.com/likes/index.html...
```

Comment: try using https://herladypinkrose.wordpress.com/2020/02/27/tallies-birds-and-scapes/ as reference Because I think the problem is that the first link had the like button on top But others require some scrolling. The first link worked very well but on the subsequent links I am getting either Time Out Exception or an element click intercepted Error. So can you give a code that makes the page scroll until it reaches the like button?

Comment: please reply fast . This is urgent