# XPath selector to get a meta tag X within an iframe

Tags: html, xpath, iframe

I've a bit of challenge that I cannot figure out.

I've an HTML doc where a nested iframe host another set of meta tags. I'd like to reach them out via an XPath query, but when testing something like `//iframe[.//meta[@name='robots']]` there is no match.
I've tried multiple combination by now, without success.

My understanding is that iframe content is normally flattened within the rendered view, hence it should be fully traversable.
In fact a simple `.//meta[@name='robots']` works fine.

[image]

Reason for asking is to intercept all meta tags in a webpage, while excluding those included in the iFrame.

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816113/3710053
So If that is true, your xpath `.//meta[@name='robots'] ` should already exclude the ones in the iframe

Comment: I'm not using Selenium here, just traversing the document with XPath and the Web Developer tool. Every hit to the above `.//meta[@name='robots']` brings me over a meta tag no matter whether it's included in the iFrame or not. Using the ancestor option doesn't work either

Comment: Could you share a url?

Comment: Yesterday I was playing around with this site https://www.maybelline.com/face-makeup/foundation-makeup/super-stay-24hr-skin-tint-with-vitamin-c?variant=129 but it could be any

Answer (score 0):

It seams like iframe as element is not recognized by Xpath.

Instead you could try for all meta not in iframe:

```
//meta[not(ancestor::body)
```

Comment: It still reach out the meta in the iframe and those that are not

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure and clear why this works the other way round than it should be, but eventually the following XPATH does the trick.

```
//meta[@name='robots'][(/descendant-or-self::iframe)]
```

Using the page given as the example in the previous comment, editing the rendered HTML to add a testing meta robots in the upper  and using the above XPATH returns only that single instance.